# Javascript event delegation between included files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have Index.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!--#include file="blocks/header.asp"-->
<!--#include file="blocks/bottom.asp"-->
<!--#include file="blocks/footer.asp"-->

</body>
</html>
```

blocks/header.asp

```
<div class="hideMeIamHeader"></div>
```

blocks/bottom.asp

```
<div class="hideMeIambottom"></div>
```

blocks/footer.asp

```
<div class="hideMeIamfooter"></div>
<button id="Hideheader">Hide Header</button>
<button id="Hidebottom">Hide bottom</button>
<button id="Hidefooter">Hide footer</button>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#Hideheader').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIamHeader').hide();});
$('#Hidebottom').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIambottom').hide();});
$('#Hidefooter').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIamfooter').hide();});

});
</script>
```

How to make this example working? I cant access `.hideMeIamHeader` and `.hideMeIambottom` from `footer.asp`

UPDATE (SOLVED)

So index.asp must look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!--#include file="blocks/header.asp"-->
<!--#include file="blocks/bottom.asp"-->
<!--#include file="blocks/footer.asp"-->
<script>
$(function() {
$('#Hideheader').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIamHeader').hide();});
$('#Hidebottom').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIambottom').hide();});
$('#Hidefooter').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIamfooter').hide();});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: No errors, just nothing hapins, it seems that javascript cant see thoose divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that these items do not exist in the DOM yet at the time the click handlers are being set. You can rectify this by using jQuery's ready() function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Hideheader').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIamHeader').hide();});
    $('#Hidebottom').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIambottom').hide();});
    $('#Hidefooter').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIamfooter').hide();});
});
```

jQuery Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: what differents `$(function() {` from `$(document).ready(function() {` ?  i think tjis is same

Comment: Definitely not the same, one is an anonymous function which fires immediately, while the ready() function waits for the DOM elements to load into memory at which point they are accessible to jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure the includes are actually loading the HTML? Check your page source and see if the div elements are showing. Also, from the example you pasted above, there is no content inside those divs, just add some text in-between the start and end tags.

I also don't see a reference to any jQuery library in your code? I.e: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes im shure all content is loaded but not accessible from script in `blocks/footer.asp` only elements in `blocks/footer.asp` is accessible by this script

Comment: Wrap your entire script in a try/catch block and do the same inside your click events and output any errors to your console in the catch blocks. This may help locating the problem. If you see anything, post it here.

Comment: No errors it just nothing hapins like no div exist, also i trying loop throught all divs on page and script only finds its own page divs do not find any included files divs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83294/discussion-between-mr-smith-and-dmitrij-holkin).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be executed once DOM is ready,

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    //Your code goes here
    $('#Hideheader').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIamHeader').hide();});
    $('#Hidebottom').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIambottom').hide();});
    $('#Hidefooter').on('click',function(){$('.hideMeIamfooter').hide();});
});
```

More Explanation: Your code is being executed when file is being loaded, and not when whole page is loaded, so when Javascript page is loaded actually page and DOM elements are not created, so jquery is not able to find the elements.

So First you need to let load all the DOM content and then you and work on DOM elements, So you code should be always executed once DOM is ready...